# Escape text with flask.escape

Tags: url, escaping, flask

In flask app, I'm sending email to user:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = 'About resetting your password'
...
reset_key = os.urandom(64).encode('base64')
link = request.host_url + "reset_pwd?rk=" + reset_key
html = '<html><body><a href="' + link + '">Reset password</a></body></html>'
part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part)
...
server = smtplib.SMTP(mail_server)  
server.starttls()
server.login(mail_username, mail_password)
server.sendmail(mail_username, to_addr, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

However, reset_key has slashes and other non-safe characters. So I did

```
link = request.host_url + "reset_pwd?rk=" + flask.escape(reset_key)
```

But when I check my email, somehow link is broken, maybe not escaped. How to properly escape texts?

EDIT: corrected a typo in code.

Comment: I just add a comment here that I have had some odd behaviour with flask.escape. It not only modifies the string so as to escape characters, it modifies the string so that if you add more characters, they will be automatically escaped even if you do NOT want those characters escaped. I have therefore used code from here for basic escaping: https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used urllib.quote(), instead of flask.escape():

```
link = request.host_url + "reset_pwd?rK=" + urllib.quote(reset_key)
```

Comment: In Python3, it's `urllib.parse.quote` in case anyone else was wondering.

Answer (score 2):

If you use gmail you can open email submenu and click `Show original` or set smtp debug level `smtp.set_debuglevel(1)` and see real email content.

Better do not use `escape` for random strings because it just escape next chars `"'&<>` see https://github.com/mitsuhiko/markupsafe/blob/master/markupsafe/_speedups.c#L33 and no reason use `escape` for `base64` string because is nothing to escape. Also `escape` return `Markup` object and better make `str(flask.escape(reset_key))` for this case.

I use next code for generate unique links:

```
def get_restore_key():
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in xrange(64))
```

Answer (score 1):

You closed the `a tag` a little early in the code you posted.

Try `html = '<html><body><a href="' + link + '">Reset password</a></body></html>'`

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, my original code doesn't have this typo. So I will update my question.